# Split the string based on regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to using regular expression. Given the string, I am trying to achieve the following:

```
actStr1 = 'st1/str2/str3'
expStr1 = 'str3'

actStr2 = 'str1/str2/str3 // str4'
expStr2 = 'str3 // str4'

actStr3 = 'a1/b1/c1 : c2'
expStr3 = 'c1 : c2'
```

In both cases, i would like to find the last string delimited by `'/'`

i.e, `'/'` like `%s\/%s`. delimiter `'/'` having strings on both sides

```
result1 = 'str3 // str4'
result2 = 'str3'
```

I tried different patterns using regex, but it incorrectly returns `'str4'` delimited by `'//'`.

How do I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: add the regex you tried

Comment: I think you need to show some real sample strings, your regex pattern and also the expected result.Otherwise it is a little confusing to read.

Comment: please find the updated question

Comment: I see the solution by Casimir et Hippolyte works but you have not accepted it. I have to wonder if the use case in the initial question is practical. Why does the string have `/` separators `//` where is the string coming from in addition you have not provided the actual code with your regex. The more context you can provide the better help you will receive.

Comment: Hi Chris, the string is a path of systems coming from backend. So in terms of path, the systems are separated by '/'. But there are cases, when the system itself can have this special ' // ', numbers , colons name. So, i am trying to get the last system name strictly using delimiter '/'. And avoid wrong name returned because of special system names

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), try to use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to directly target what you need:

```js
var testStrings = [ 'str1/str2/str3',
                    'str1/str2/str3 // str4',
                    'a1/b1/c1 : c2' ];

var re = new RegExp('[^/]*(?://+[^/]*)*$');

testStrings.forEach(function(elt) {
    console.log(elt.match(re)[0]);
});
/* str3
   str3 // str4
   c1 : c2 */
```

Less straight forward, you can also use a replacement strategy with [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The idea is to remove all until the last slash not preceded and not followed by an other slash:

```
var re = new RegExp('(?:.*[^/]|^)/(?!/)');

testStrings.forEach(function(elt) {
    console.log(elt.replace(re, ''));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @revo, but it seems that this feature doesn't return the good array (the index of the match and the input string are missing). But In the futur I will try to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\/(\w+(?:$| .*))
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/t732R0/2)**

And grab the content from capturing group

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this considering using arrays too!

```
function lastSlug(str) {
  // remove the '//' from the string
  var b = str.replace('//', '');
  // find the last index of '/'
  var c = b.lastIndexOf('/')  + 1;
  // return anything after that '/' 
  var d = str.slice(c);
  return d;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zapavavisu/edit?js,console)